# UIView's Backing CALayer Does Not Reenable Implicit Animations In Block Anymore?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, calayer

According to [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html),

> The UIView class disables layer animations by default but reenables them inside animation blocks.

backing layer's implicit animations should be reenables within the UIView's animation blocks. In fact, this official snippets

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{ 

// Change the opacity implicitly.
myView.layer.opacity = 0.0;

// Change the position explicitly.
CABasicAnimation* theAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
theAnim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:myView.layer.position];
theAnim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:myNewPosition];
theAnim.duration = 3.0;
[myView.layer addAnimation:theAnim forKey:@"AnimateFrame"];
}];
```

attempts to trigger implicit animations on the backing layer. Also, according the the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096921/why-do-docs-indicate-calayer-animations-must-be-in-uiview-animation-blocks), this is the expected behavior. This [blog's post](https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/view-layer-synergy/) also confirmed that

> the view returns the NSNull object outside of the block and returns a CABasicAnimation inside of the block

However, this is currently not true. From my simple test, UIView's animation block does not reenable the implicit animations of back CALayer. In addition, actionForLayer:forKey: now return NSNull both inside and outside of the animation block. **Does this means the official is out-dated and this is no longer the expected behavior?**

Comment: Do you see the same behavior (and get `NSNull` from `actionForLayer:forKey:`) in iOS 9 and 8 as well? Or is this behavior only in iOS 10?

Comment: I have the same behavior on iOS9, and have not test older ones yet.

Comment: From my searches, the implicit animations seems to work in UIView's animation block as documented only as far as 2014.

Comment: There was some big under the hood changes to UIView animations in 2014 to better support interruptible animations (see [Building Interruptible and Responsive Interactions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=236)). I suspect that this new behavior is a result of those changes. Whether or not it's intentional change in behavior, I don't know. You can always file or radar with the hopes of either getting the bug(?) fixed or getting the documentation updated.

Comment: I just watch the video, it seems that the changes could actually be rooted from the 2014's under the hood upgrades. Your answer is the missing information that point to a plausible explanation. If you don't mind to make a formal answer so I can accept it. I will file a bug report with Apple in the mean time. Thanks.